# windows 2008 r2 fail to restore

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We have one dell R710 server with windows 2008 R2(SP1)

The partitions are: `C:40gb, D: 1.71TB, E:1.71TB,F: 124GB.`

I used windows server backup tools to backup the C drivers (OS drivers) and system data to F drivers.

Below are the steps I tested to recover the backup image.

1. I copy the backup folder(the whole windowsImageBackup) to the root in the external hard disk.
2. Plug in the external to other server(testing only)
3. Restarting the server with booting from windows 2008 r2 CD.
4. Click repair your computer
5. After system scanning system image, it will give me message windows cannot find a system image on this server

Any suggestion? Or we can using `wbadmin` to restore?

Comment: wonder if the repair cd has to be sp1 also?

Comment: Yes, I used the windows 2008 R2 with SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Install clean OS matching the same patch level as previous system. Restore all the required files, restore System State. Reboot.
The system should come up prompting you for drivers to install.

Comment: Hi guy, 
thanks! But I just want to try to use the windows restore funtion! Could you help me to find out and conquer this error?